# MERGE BY in SAS - udesirable results with sashelp.class

Tags: merge, sas, dataset

I want to merge two databases in SAS. I have a task to use MERGE  statement for that, although I would prefer to do so using SQL. Nevertheless here is the code I use:

```
DATA grades;
    INPUT Name $ grades;
    DATALINES;
    Alice 5
    Carol 1
    John 5
    Robert 5
    Thomas 3
    Judy 6
    ;
    PROC SORT DATA=grades;
    BY Name;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=SASHELP.class;
PROC PRINT DATA=grades;

DATA merged;
    MERGE SASHELP.class grades;
    BY Name;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=merged;
```

The final result I obtain is:

```
    Obs Name    Sex Age Height  Weight  grades
    1   Alice       .   .       .       5
    2   Carol       .   .       .       1
    3   John        .   .       .       5
    4   Judy        .   .       .       6
    5   Robert      .   .       .       5
    6   Thomas      .   .       .       3
    7   Alfred  M   14  69.0    112.5   .
    8   Alice   F   13  56.5    84.0    .
    9   Barbara F   13  65.3    98.0    .
    10  Carol   F   14  62.8    102.5   .
    11  Henry   M   14  63.5    102.5   .
    12  James   M   12  57.3    83.0    .
    13  Jane    F   12  59.8    84.5    .
    14  Janet   F   15  62.5    112.5   .
    15  Jeffrey M   13  62.5    84.0    .
    16  John    M   12  59.0    99.5    .
    17  Joyce   F   11  51.3    50.5    .
    18  Judy    F   14  64.3    90.0    .
    19  Louise  F   12  56.3    77.0    .
    20  Mary    F   15  66.5    112.0   .
    21  Philip  M   16  72.0    150.0   .
    22  Robert  M   12  64.8    128.0   .
    23  Ronald  M   15  67.0    133.0   .
    24  Thomas  M   11  57.5    85.0    .
    25  William M   15  66.5    112.0   .
```

If I modify the code by deleting "BY Name" in Merge statement results are not much better:

```
Obs Name    Sex Age Height  Weight  grades
1   Alice   M   14  69.0    112.5   5
2   Carol   F   13  56.5    84.0    1
3   John    F   13  65.3    98.0    5
4   Judy    F   14  62.8    102.5   6
5   Robert  M   14  63.5    102.5   5
6   Thomas  M   12  57.3    83.0    3
7   Jane    F   12  59.8    84.5    .
8   Janet   F   15  62.5    112.5   .
9   Jeffrey M   13  62.5    84.0    .
10  John    M   12  59.0    99.5    .
11  Joyce   F   11  51.3    50.5    .
12  Judy    F   14  64.3    90.0    .
13  Louise  F   12  56.3    77.0    .
14  Mary    F   15  66.5    112.0   .
15  Philip  M   16  72.0    150.0   .
16  Robert  M   12  64.8    128.0   .
17  Ronald  M   15  67.0    133.0   .
18  Thomas  M   11  57.5    85.0    .
19  William M   15  66.5    112.0   .
```

Seem s to work until you look at data for Robert for example. The results should be:

```
Name    Sex Age Height  Weight Grade
Robert  M   12  64.8    128.0  5
```

not:

```
Name    Sex Age Height  Weight Grade
Robert  M   14  63.5    102.5   5
```

It looks that for example Alfred was overwritten. Why data are not consistent? What have I done wrong?

Comment: I thin your syntax is missing `in`statement. Try: `DATA merged;
    MERGE SASHELP.class(in=a) grades(in=b);
    BY Name;
if a and b; /*or any combination*/
RUN;`

Comment: Do NOT indent the in-line data. That is probably why you ended up with spaces or other non-graphic characters in the front of the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would appear to be a data issue in which the names in the grade table have one or more leading spaces.  The default output styles for HTML and PDF do not make the leading spaces visible.  `ODS LISTING` and view the output in the `OUTPUT` window should show a leading space.

You can 'fix' the issue with `name = left(name);` in the `grades` step.  You can force the issue with `name = ' ' || left(name);`.  Check the underlying character data with '$HEX' format.

```
PROC REPORT data=grades;
  columns name grades name=namehex;
  define namehex / format=$hex20.;
run;
```

A merge without `BY` is a special edge case; generally when you know a-priori un-keyed data in table A is related 1:1 row-wise to data in table B.

Comment: Apparently there are trailing spaces:
Alice: 416C696365202020, 
Carol: 4361726F6C202020, 
John : A6F686E20202020, 
Judy: A75647920202020, 
Robert: 526F626572742020, 
Thomas: 54686F6D61732020

Comment: The trailing spaces are a normal part of SAS character variables.  The leading should be of concern.  The `41` in Alice, `43` in Carol and `54` in Thomas are as expected.  However, hex code `A6` in John, and `A7` in Judy indicate some sort of data or issue.  Don't forget to mark answers when appropriate -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers